# nested for loop to display hierarchical data

Tags: django, python-3.x

I need to display a very simplified Gantt view in a project management app. For this I have a hierarchy of milestones, work-packages and tasks in my database.
If I do an oversimplified datastructure of

```
data = [    [ 'milestone',
                ['segment','segment'],
                    []
            ], 
            ['milestone',
                ['segment'],
                    ['task','task','task']
            ], 
            ['milestone',
                ['segment'],
                    []
            ] 
        ]
```

And use a code in my template like below, the display is correct.

```
<table class="table">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th></th>
              <th></th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>

            {% for x, y, z in data %}
                <tr >
                    <td style="color:red;">{{ x }}</td>
                </tr>
                {% for yy in y %}
                    <tr>
                        <td style="background-color: lightgrey; padding-left: 20px;">{{ yy }}</td>
                    </tr>
                    {% for zz in z %}
                        <tr>
                            <td style="background-color: grey; padding-left: 40px;">{{ zz }}</td>
                        </tr>
                    {% endfor %}
                {% endfor %}
            {% endfor %}
           </tbody>
      </table>
```

Now if I want to get realistic data structure with more work-packages(segments) summarising tasks, this solution does not work.
See my data structure 'approach' to be more realistic

```
x_new = [   [ 'milestone',
                ['segment','segment'],
                    []
            ], 
            ['milestone',
                ['segment',
                    ['task','task','task'],
                 'segment',
                 'segment',
                    ['task']
                 ]
            ], 
            ['milestone',
                ['segment'],
                    []
            ] 
        ]
```

Running this structure, I simply get the task hierarchy be displayed as yet another segment (sound logical).
Has anyone a good idea on how to do this properly?

many thanks

Comment: Have a look at this [package](https://django-mptt.github.io/django-mptt/templates.html).

Comment: Is it necessary to store your data in nested list? it doesn't actually promises that which list of task related to which segment, instead try using list of dictionaries of milestone contains segment as key and task list as key-element/value

Comment: thanks so far, I will look into your suggestion